# timespan and UTC

Tags: .net

I have a Timespan variable, which has time in local time zone but for a database ( cold type time) I need to pass UTC . How do I do this?
Also I need to get UTC to Local time to populate Timespan variable on pageLoad.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suppose I would load the TimeSpan into a DateTime, then get the universal time from the DateTime and convert it back again.

```
var dt = new DateTime( timeSpan.Ticks );
var utc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: Following won't convert 8PM eastern correctly to UTC 

Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
  Dim dtUniversal As New TimeSpan(dt.Ticks)

Comment: Are the ticks representing different things perhaps? Different systems use different tick representations--usually the date to start counting milliseconds from. If you can convert your timespan into specific values for year, month, day, etc. you can build a DateTime from those values and then convert it to UTC.

Comment: As you suggested, How do I build datetime? All I am storing in the database is hour and default minutes and seconds are alwyas 00.  eg. My value stored is 01:00:00 how do I convert this to dateTime? - thanks

Comment: I will accept this one I made few changes but it was a good starting point for me - thanks

Comment: This will only work if the TimeSpan has the date component included, not just the Time. In my case I'm converting a TimeOfDay to UTC, so this code example will always result in 01/01/0001, and not take daylight savings into account.

Comment: i used your method to do so and I now want to present this UTC Timespan in UTC DateTime format.. can you pls answer my question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208648/get-utc-datetime-by-adding-server-date-and-utc-timespan-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6):

A problem I found with a couple of the previous answers is that creating a DateTime from ticks results in a date/time such as `0001-01-01 04:00:00`. If you're in a timezone with a positive UTC offset when the framework attempts to subtract say 10 hours it goes below `DateTime.MinValue` and while it doesn't throw an exception you end up with a TimeSpan containing `00:00:00` instead of the correct result.

The answer by [Ali Sepehri.Kh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085633/ali-sepehri-kh) gets around this underflow by using `.AddDays(1)` however because the date is always January 1 for areas that observe DST you can end up with an incorrect result. Because I was only interested in timespans for the current day I ended up using a modified version of Ali's code that uses the current date as the base and adds the TimeSpan to it:

```
public static TimeSpan LocalTimeSpanToUTC(TimeSpan ts)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(ts);
    DateTime dtUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan tsUtc = dtUtc.TimeOfDay;
    return tsUtc;
}

public static TimeSpan UTCTimeSpanToLocal(TimeSpan tsUtc)
{
     DateTime dtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Add(tsUtc);
     DateTime dt = dtUtc.ToLocalTime();
     TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay;
     return ts;
}
```

Comment: you need to add 'this' to be extension methods, e.g.: (this TimeSpan ts), (this TimeSpan tsUtc)

Answer (score 5):

```
class TimeConversion
{
    public static TimeSpan LocalTimeSpanToUTC(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts.Ticks).AddDays(1);
        DateTime dtUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeSpan tsUtc = dtUtc.TimeOfDay;

        return tsUtc;
    }

    public static TimeSpan UTCTimeSpanToLocal(TimeSpan tsUtc)
    {
        DateTime dtUtc = new DateTime(tsUtc.Ticks).AddDays(1);
        DateTime dt = dtUtc.ToLocalTime();
        TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay;

        return ts;
    }
}
```

Comment: What the reason of AddDays(1) ?

Comment: @Miles I can answer that because I tried another answer and it didn't work because I'm in a +10 UTC zone and it couldn't subtract anything from the date 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeSpan LocalTimeToUTCTime(TimeSpan localTime)
{
    var dt = new DateTime(localTime.Ticks);
    var utc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    return new TimeSpan(utc.Ticks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today. The best way to do this would be to add the `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` without a time component.

```cs
var dateTimeLocal = DateTime.Today.Add(timeSpan);
```

The `DateTimeKind` for this will be set to `DateTimeKind.Local` by default. Set `DateTimeKind` to unspecified because this is not *actually* local time (which is wherever this code will be running) but rather the time in the original timezone:

```cs
var dateTimeUnspecified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeLocal, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Then convert the `DateTime` to UTC with the source `TimeZoneInfo` (the timezone that the original time was meant to be in) (this is the second parameter `sourceTimeZone`):

```cs
var utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeUnspecified, sourceTimeZone);
```

Voila!