# Get UTC DateTime by adding server date and UTC TimeSpan in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, logic

I have UTC TimeSpan in my DB, which I got as following

```
item.UTCStartTime = new DateTime(item.StartTime.Ticks).ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay;
```

Now I need current UTC DateTime along with my UTCStartTime. I am doing it as follows, but it seems to be providing wrong time.

```
DateTime time = DateTimeHelper.ConvertUTCToCurrentTimeZone(new DateTime(item.UTCStartTime.Ticks).ToUniversalTime());
```

Then I changed the above line like this

```
DateTime time = DateTimeHelper.ConvertUTCToCurrentTimeZone(new DateTime()).Add(item.UTCStartTime);
```

<strike>Now I think I am getting the correct time except the period. It is showing the opposite of the correct one. eg: PM for AM and AM for PM</strike> **UPDATE: Sorry, the time is still showing wrongly**.

> NOTE: The **DateTimeHelper.ConvertUTCToCurrentTimeZone()** is just a
> method to convert the UTC to a new datetime of a desired timezone by
> TimeZoneId

Comment: What is a "UTC Timespan"? A timespan - to me - would be something like "48 hours", for which a TZ designator makes no sense. Now, if you define it to be "from DateTime, to DateTime" - that's a different thing. As far as I am concerned, I'd need more details, here. For example the implementation of the DateTimeHelper would be useful. Also: are you aware of the existence of [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Maybe also have a look into this: [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973825(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Disclaimer: It's a rather old article and I am not sure how much of it still applies.

Comment: Umm... clarifying my problem. I want to convert the UTC TimeSpan to TimeSpan of India Standard Time...

Comment: Again: _"What **is** a 'UTC TimeSpan'"_? Definitely not a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: I understand. u r right. A timespan is just a time interval. its a waste of converting it to UTC form right? Did I get you?

Comment: Depends on what you are actually talking about. The span between time x and time y may indeed differ if x and y are UTC or local (think daylight savings). But the span itself is just a measure of difference. Not absolute. Like "Raheem is 15 cm taller than Rajesh". There you have a span, but you know nothing about the respective absolute heights of both. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: ^^ I'll try to find a good example ... may take some time.

Comment: Nope not necessary I believe.. I just got the thing working.. now.. did this.. new DateTime(item.StartTime).ToString("hh:mm tt")

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `new DateTime()` returns a value that can be displayed as *1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM* (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0). Pretty much Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second set to 0. Also, it is returned without specified timezone (local or UTC), thus converting it to UTC does nothing.

```
var date = new DateTime();
Console.WriteLine(date);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToUniversalTime());

// Output
01/01/0001 00:00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:00
```

Because of that, your date will definetly be off. If you are sure, that `item.UTCStartTime` contains correct UTC time, add it to today's date, can be done with:

```
var utcTimeToday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Add(item.UTCStartTime);
```

Comment: _"Also, it is returned as UTC timezone."_ where do you get that from? This [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fJILcr) shows, it is "unspecified".

Comment: ^^ It has a 0 hrs _offset_, though. But that's not exactly the same.

Comment: @tsveds  I just tried the answer.. not successfull.. I'll do one thing... i'll update my question..

Comment: @Fildor good point, will update my answer.